# Proteger script com dados de usuários?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, proteção

Atualmente em minha página carrego alguns scripts retornados por PHP da seguinte forma:

```
$(".div").html($("<script />", {
     src: 'http://www.dominio.com/functions/dados.php?user='+xxxx+'&acao='+xxxx+''
}));
```

Dentro de dados.php já estou verificando se o usuário está logado, e se o `id` do mesmo corresponde ao `GET user` o que até o momento funciona para evitar que outro usuário tente brincar de Dora Aventureira explorando as URL's e acabar se deparando com o conteúdo de outro usuário, minhas dúvidas são:

1. Este seria o melhor método para proteger os dados de um determinado
   usuário?
2. Se não, como posso melhorar a chamada desse script e evitar o uso do
   mesmo por usuários Dora Aventureira?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sem Autenticação - Solução Rápida

O id do usuário pode ser um UUID, que é um identificador com chances quase nulas de ser duplicado ou adivinhado manualmente.

> Equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate – [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates).

Vai ficar algo como:

```
$(".div").html($("<script />", {
     src: 'http://www.dominio.com/functions/dados.php?user=1546058f-5a25-4334-85ae-e68f2a44bbaf&acao=qualquer_acao'
}));
```

Infelizmente não há uma implementação nativa em PHP, mas você pode tentar essa classe ([fonte](https://gist.github.com/dahnielson/508447)):

```
<?php
/**
 * UUID class
 *
 * The following class generates VALID RFC 4122 COMPLIANT
 * Universally Unique IDentifiers (UUID) version 3, 4 and 5.
 *
 * UUIDs generated validates using OSSP UUID Tool, and output
 * for named-based UUIDs are exactly the same. This is a pure
 * PHP implementation.
 *
 * @author Andrew Moore
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959
 */
class UUID
{
    /**
     * Generate v3 UUID
     *
     * Version 3 UUIDs are named based. They require a namespace (another 
     * valid UUID) and a value (the name). Given the same namespace and 
     * name, the output is always the same.
     * 
     * @param   uuid    $namespace
     * @param   string  $name
     */
    public static function v3($namespace, $name)
    {
        if(!self::is_valid($namespace)) return false;
        // Get hexadecimal components of namespace
        $nhex = str_replace(array('-','{','}'), '', $namespace);
        // Binary Value
        $nstr = '';
        // Convert Namespace UUID to bits
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($nhex); $i+=2) 
        {
            $nstr .= chr(hexdec($nhex[$i].$nhex[$i+1]));
        }
        // Calculate hash value
        $hash = md5($nstr . $name);
        return sprintf('%08s-%04s-%04x-%04x-%12s',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        substr($hash, 0, 8),
        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        substr($hash, 8, 4),
        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 3
        (hexdec(substr($hash, 12, 4)) & 0x0fff) | 0x3000,
        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        (hexdec(substr($hash, 16, 4)) & 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
        // 48 bits for "node"
        substr($hash, 20, 12)
        );
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Generate v4 UUID
     * 
     * Version 4 UUIDs are pseudo-random.
     */
    public static function v4() 
    {
        return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
        );
    }
    /**
     * Generate v5 UUID
     * 
     * Version 5 UUIDs are named based. They require a namespace (another 
     * valid UUID) and a value (the name). Given the same namespace and 
     * name, the output is always the same.
     * 
     * @param   uuid    $namespace
     * @param   string  $name
     */
    public static function v5($namespace, $name) 
    {
        if(!self::is_valid($namespace)) return false;
        // Get hexadecimal components of namespace
        $nhex = str_replace(array('-','{','}'), '', $namespace);
        // Binary Value
        $nstr = '';
        // Convert Namespace UUID to bits
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($nhex); $i+=2) 
        {
            $nstr .= chr(hexdec($nhex[$i].$nhex[$i+1]));
        }
        // Calculate hash value
        $hash = sha1($nstr . $name);
        return sprintf('%08s-%04s-%04x-%04x-%12s',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        substr($hash, 0, 8),
        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        substr($hash, 8, 4),
        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 5
        (hexdec(substr($hash, 12, 4)) & 0x0fff) | 0x5000,
        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        (hexdec(substr($hash, 16, 4)) & 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
        // 48 bits for "node"
        substr($hash, 20, 12)
        );
    }
    public static function is_valid($uuid) {
        return preg_match('/^\{?[0-9a-f]{8}\-?[0-9a-f]{4}\-?[0-9a-f]{4}\-?'.
                      '[0-9a-f]{4}\-?[0-9a-f]{12}\}?$/i', $uuid) === 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Ao criar o usuário, coloque o ID como:

```
include 'UUID.php';
$id = UUID::v4();
```

## Autenticação

Porém, a forma mais óbvia de evitar roubo de informações é adicionar autenticação ao seu sistema. Seja manualmente (registro e login criados por você) ou via Facebook e afins.

Você transformará a página `dados.php` como privada, exigindo os dados na sessão, e então poderá incluí-la sem o ID do usuário, pois o ID é identificado na session diretamente na `dados.php`.

```
$(".div").html($("<script />", {
     src: 'http://www.dominio.com/functions/dados.php?acao='+xxxx
}));
```

Comment: Muito interessante o uso de UUID estava usando sequências randômicas para gerar o ID dos meus usuários, mas vou mudar, quanto ao script gostei da ideia de autenticar dentro da página dados.php, obrigado @AlfredBaudisch